# Extracting values from Haskell type synonyms

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a Dominoes game for class and can't wrap my head around custom types. I have:

```
type DomsPlayer = Hand -> Board -> (Domino,End)
...
playTurn :: DomsPlayer -> (Int, Hand, Board)
playTurn hand1 board1 = (score, hand2, board2)
  where (dom, end) = simplePlayer hand1 board1
                     board2 = resMaybe (playDom dom board1 end)
                     hand2 = remove dom hand1
                     score = scoreBoard board2
```

Trying to load this gives me the errors:

> Dominoes.hs:43:3: error:
>
> • Couldn't match expected type ‘(Int, Hand, Board)’
>                    with actual type ‘Board -> (Int, b0, Board)’
>
> • The equation(s) for ‘playTurn’ have two arguments,
>        but its type ‘DomsPlayer -> (Int, Hand, Board)’ has only one
>
> |
>   43 |   playTurn hand1 board1 = (score, hand2, board2)    |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
>
> Dominoes.hs:44:37: error:
>
> • Couldn't match type ‘Hand -> Board -> (Domino, End)’
>                        with ‘[Domino]’
>
> Expected type: Hand
>         Actual type: DomsPlayer
>
> • Probable cause: ‘hand1’ is applied to too few arguments
>
> In the first argument of ‘simplePlayer’, namely ‘hand1’
>
> In the expression: simplePlayer hand1 board1
>
> In a pattern binding: (dom, end) = simplePlayer hand1 board1
>
> |
>   44 |     where (dom, end) = simplePlayer hand1 board1    |

How do I retrieve the values from DomsPlayer?

Comment: It looks like the definition of DomsPlayer is a type synonym for a function, not a data type.

Comment: Your type `DomsPlayer` is a function of two arguments (`Hand` and `Board`).

Your function `playTurn` take as argument such a `DomsPlayer` function and returns a triple. However, your pattern match for `playTurn` has 2 arguments (`hand1` and `board1`). This does not fit together.

Comment: I give an answer but in order to help you I want to know what are you trying to do. Do you want to recieve a ```Hand``` and a ```Board```? Or do you want a ```(Domino, End)``` too? Clearly you are defining a function, because ```DomsPlayer``` is a synonym of function.

Comment: I want a (Domino, End) as well.

Comment: Ok, so why did you create ```DomsPlayer``` for? To group ```Hand```, ```Board``` and ```(Domino, End)```?

Comment: DomsPlayer groups the strategies for choosing a move; playTurn plays the chosen move and updates the game state.

Comment: Ok, do you want the strategy to be a function? Because that is the way you defined it. I think it could be a triple instead.

Comment: it looks a simple type mismatch to me. this should be straightforward confusion. might i kindly ask why people up vote it?

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr because it's a valid well formed question showing code, effort and the question is very clear

Comment: Voting to close as too broad, since you seem to be fundamentally misunderstanding a large amount of haskell syntax but I don't know how to help you other than to direct you to a good haskell book. Some things that might help: 1) in your code you return the triple `(score, hand2, board2)`, but do nothing with the bound values `dom` and `end` (always compile with `-Wall` to notice this kind of thing). 2) the function arrow (`->`) is right associative, so e.g. these are the same: `a -> b -> c` , `a -> (b -> c)`

Comment: 3) there is absolutely nothing at the _value_ level affected by `type`; when you create a type synonym you're essentially creating a simple macro that expands in a type signature

Answer (score 0):

If you replace this `DomsPlayer` with its definition

```
type DomsPlayer = Hand -> Board -> (Domino,End)

playTurn :: (Hand -> Board -> (Domino,End)) -> (Int, Hand, Board)
```

you will see that playTurn recieves only one parameter, not two.

I don't know what you are trying to do, but clearly you will need to recieve `Hand` and `Board` as separate params:

```
playTurn :: Hand -> Board -> ... -> (Int, Hand, Board)
```

And I don't know, maybe also pass a function of type `DomsPlayer` too, and apply it to those separate arguments.

But that is your error.